# Comparing Two Rings $k[T]/(T^n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to understand an ambiguous statement (to me at least).

> Let $k=\mathbb{F}_p$ be the field with $p$ elements. Compare the two 
>   rings $k[T]/(T^n)$ and $Z/(p^n)$ for $n\geq 2$. Show that their 
>   elements can be written uniquely in the form 
>   $a_0+a_1T+\cdots+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}$ or $a_0+a_1p+\cdots+a_{n-1}p^{n-1}$ 
>   with $a_i \in \{0,1,\cdots,p-1\}$ for $i=0,\cdots,n-1$; determine the 
>   addition and multiplication of these power series in the two rings, an
>   note that they differ only by the $p$-adic ''carry''.

I have managed to show that every element can be written in the given forms (the first one is direct and for the second one I first wrote everything in the base $p$, then the terms with powers greater than $n-1$ were included in the ideal). Then, I defined addition and multiplication in the most obvious way (though I am not sure if it is correct, basically I used the base logic and increased the next one by $1$ if the sum exceeds $p-1$). However, my biggest problem is that I do not know what the author means by saying ''p-adic carry''. It would be great if you could check whether I am on the right track and also the ''p-adic carry'' problem of course (my guess is that he means the isomorphism between).

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you defined addition/multiplication the same for both (just with $T$s and $p$s swapped), or differently. If you did it differently, then the "$p$-adic carry" is exactly the difference between the two definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $k[T]/(T^n)$, if you add $a_0 + a_1 T + \dots + a_{n-1} T^{n-1}$ and $b_0 + b_1 T + \dots + b_{n-1} T^{n-1}$ you get $(a_0 + b_0) + (a_1 + b_1)T + \dots + (a_{n-1} + b_{n-1})T^{n-1}$.

In $Z/(p^n)$, if you add $a_0 + a_1 p + \dots + a_{n-1} p^{n-1}$ and $b_0 + b_1 p + \dots + b_{n-1} p^{n-1}$ you get $(a_0 + b_0) + (a_1 + b_1)p + \dots + (a_{n-1} + b_{n-1})p^{n-1}$. Here, however, $a_i + b_i$ need not be in $\{0, \dots, p-1\}$. To 'repair' that, you change $a_i + b_i$ to $a_i + b_i - p$ and $a_{i+1} + b_{i+1}$ to $a_{i+1} + b_{i+1} - 1$, 'carrying' the $p$, just as you describe. This is very likely what the author means by the '$p$-adic carry'.

Comment: But the same problem can occur in $k[T]/(T^n)$, I mean $a_{i}+b_{i}$ might be greater than $p$. So, don't we need to define both in the same way?

Comment: $k = {\Bbb F}_p$, so there $a_i + b_i - p = a_i + b_i$.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know what he meant by ''p-adic'' carry.